# Where is svcutil.exe in visual studio 2017?

Tags: windows, svcutil.exe

I just downloaded visual studio 2017 for svcutil.exe but I can't find it. Do you know where it is?

Comment: Use the Visual Studio 2017 > Developer Command Prompt shortcut in the Start menu to run it.  Typing "where svcutil.exe" shows you where it is located.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be a part of the Windows SDK, as you can see in following directory excerpt:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\<SDK_Version>\bin\NETFX <NETX_Version> Tools\<architecture>
```

Comment: When I go in the windows sdks, i only have windows kits and windows phone.

Comment: And what in "tools", "extensions and updates", SDKs? (In the Visual Studio menu)

Comment: There is a marketplace, but I don't know what I'm supposed to download. When I type svcutil.exe, many things appear.